# Why isn't Laravel's Response Facade a Facade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-facade

If you look at the Laravel's configuration, you'll see an alias has been setup for the symbol `Response`

```
'aliases' => array(
    'Response'        => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response',
```

The namespace on the actual class, and Laravel's general pattern of using aliases for global access to laravel facade objects make this seems like `Response` is a facade.  However, if you look at the actual definition of the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response` class

```
#File: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Response.php
namespace Illuminate\Support\Facades;

//...    
class Response {
```

We can see, again, that the class exists in the `Illuminate\Support\Facades` namespace, but it does **not** extend the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade` class, nor does is implement a  `getFacadeAccessor` method which means, confusingly, it's not *really* a facade.

Does anyone know why this is? i.e. is there a compelling framework reason why this class in the Facade namespace isn't implemented as an actual Laravel facade?